# Gravatar API for Java

Tags: java, api, email, gravatar

Where should I start if I want to integrate Gravatars for the users in my Java application?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [jgravatar](https://github.com/ralfebert/jgravatar) and than just use methods like the once bellow:

```
import jgravatar.Gravatar;
import jgravatar.GravatarDefaultImage;
import jgravatar.GravatarRating;

public static String getGravatar160pxUrl(String email) {
    Gravatar gravatar = new Gravatar();
    gravatar.setSize(160);
    gravatar.setRating(GravatarRating.GENERAL_AUDIENCES);
    gravatar.setDefaultImage(GravatarDefaultImage.IDENTICON);
    return gravatar.getUrl(email);
}

public static String getGravatar80pxUrl(String email) {
    Gravatar gravatar = new Gravatar();
    gravatar.setRating(GravatarRating.GENERAL_AUDIENCES);
    gravatar.setDefaultImage(GravatarDefaultImage.IDENTICON);
    return gravatar.getUrl(email);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

if anyone interested, here comes Android version too...

hope this helps...
https://github.com/wareninja/gravatar-for-android

Android library for Gravatar stuff, current features;

- Load Gravatar image using AsyncTask
- Load and Parse Gravatar Profile using
  AsyncTask

Comment: Is there a reason no updates have been done in 2 years? Gravatar did not evolve?

Comment: good question! well... it has been long time that I didn't check gravatar API, i'll revisit and see if any update needed. plz let me know if anything specific is needed, your contribution is also welcome

Answer (score 2):

may be you can use my gravatar4j (https://github.com/yingzhuo/gravatar4j)

just do this in you jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="gravatar4j" uri="https://github.com/yingzhuo/gravatar4j/functions" %>
```

and to this

```
<img alt="" src="${gravatar4j:from('yingzhor@gmail.com', 160)}">
```

'160' means size in pixels, by the way.